Repeated Capacitor Failure on Single-Phase Pump Connected to Pressure Controller (230V)
I’m facing a recurring issue with a single-phase capacitor-run pump installed at a client's site. The pump is connected to a pressure controller, and within one month, we’ve had three breakdowns, each caused by a damaged capacitor. After multiple breakdowns, we replaced the entire pump with a new one, and the new pump experienced the exact same issue—capacitor failure within a short time. Here’s a detailed breakdown of the situation:
Pump type: Single-phase capacitor-run pump.
Capacitor failure: The capacitor burns out after a short period of operation (within 2 or 3 days).
Power supply: The site operates on a standard single-phase (230 V/50 Hz) power supply, but there are lot of solar electricity generation around the area and also at the client house, which is given to the common grid. But we haven’t yet checked for voltage fluctuations or instability.
Additional factors:
Pressure controller: The pump is controlled by a pressure controller. Could the controller be causing the issue?
Voltage supply: We suspect possible voltage fluctuations due to solar electricity generation, but we haven’t recorded them yet. Could this be the primary cause?
Motor overload: We have checked if the motor is drawing excessive current. But nothin recorded while testing. Could motor overload cause continuous capacitor damage?
Has anyone encountered similar issues with capacitor failure on pumps connected to pressure controllers? I would appreciate any help on where to begin troubleshooting or what checks to prioritize.

How often is the motor turning on/off?  Each time the motor starts there is a "surge" of current in the cap.  If the controller is cycling too often the cap will get hot and fail. See https://www.aces.edu/blog/topics/farming/start-and-run-capacitors-for-electric-motors/

Also check the waveform of the AC mains. If the system runs from an inverter, it might produce a square wave, with sharp steps, rather than a sine wave. A stepped wave has high-frequency components, which might raise current through the capacitor, or cause resonance with the motor's inductance.
